# How to apply blur effect to background when modal is opened in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, modal-dialog

I think the title is not easy to understand, What I mean is when we use UI library like `Bootstrap`, `Material UI`, etc... When we click the button to show modal, the background opacity except its modal is changed to dark.

https://material-ui.com/components/modal/#modal

You can see in above url when you click the button to show modal. The background changed like blur effect.

I don't use above library, I just want to make it myself. Below is my code, Can you give me some hints? 
I think I might to apply style to `document`, Is there any good idea?

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-newton-icl0e

Comment: I'm a bit late but here is another approach https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-dawn-qq7uq maybe you find it useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to wrap the `<Modal />` with another div which will be the "overlay" and will has the dark background

```js
const ModalContainer = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
`;
```

```html
<ModalContainer>
  <Modal>I am a modal, I want to be special.</Modal>
</ModalContainer>
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-lake-ic9jx

If you want to place the modal exactly in the center, you can use flexbox

```js
const ModalContainer = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const Modal = styled.div`
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 200px;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with CSS. Change the opacity level on other elements. Properties you may require would be `filter` and `opacity` Try [Ant Design](https://3x.ant.design/) as you're using React JS. This has components prebuild with properties like `visible` to make background darker when some element is active.